# Developers with C# , VBA, and Python want to send the data into database

Tags: sql-server, database, vba, ssis, generic-interface

I have a question, I have so much confusing. I am recent graduate, started working in a company there lots of old data in text files, so I have organised all these data by using Python and i have generated a excel file. so for the situation good.

The problem, for new incoming data of sensors from different developers

1. Most of the guys using VB scripting , people test the data and saving data in text files by using delimited (, and |).
2. some other guy developing projects in C#, these people got some different kind of text data with different delimiters(: and ,)

The question I have to set up the database, how can i take all these developers data , automatically into the  data base, for these text data I have created column names and structure for it.

Do i need to develop individual interface for all these developers or is there any common interface i have to focus or where to start is still lacking me.

I hope people out there understood my situation.

Best regards
Vinod

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This is really not the sort of question that belongs on SO

Comment: one you define a general separation delimiter for all developers or two you make a table for that every developer can use there own separation delimiter or three you use XML which you can valid with XML schema.

Comment: @RaymondNijland all developers using their own delimiter. for each case i have developed a data structure.

Comment: Sounds like customization work for every developer to me read custom API for every developer.. But it's hard to suggest something without [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like @RiggsFolly said already.

Comment: I would get the developers to all agree on a common standard, if you can. If not then you'll have to customise your import procedure slightly for each different delimiter. If the delimiter is the only thing which varies, then specifying the delimiter could be just a variable which you input into an otherwise identical import process each time you run it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland that means do i need develop different customized API for developers, in there own programming language or any common interface that can handle all these developers data??

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your feedback, so once if all agreed to one standard , then , what is the possible way for it??

Comment: Using MySQL, or using SQL Server? You tagged both, it's not clear which system you're actually using. Either way you can easily google how to import text files using either one, it's really common. You'll get lots of results. I see no particular reason to repeat all that info here. If you'd tried an import process and got stuck on some specific issue, then that would be a different matter.

Comment: I don't think you need to write an interface for each developer. All are text files, different delimiters and perhaps different columns. I would write just one generic interface and a configuration file for each developer. The configuration file will tell you the columns, the delimiter, the destination table and so on.

Comment: @ADyson SQL server 2017, yes ..i done importing the old data ..i done..that  but for new data , i have  to save the data directly into to database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...you mean you want to append it to an existing table instead of creating a new one? I'm sure you can google that too... SSIS is probably your friend if it's SQL Server world

Comment: P.S. Why did you tag mysql then? Don't tag things you aren't using. And read the tag descriptions before you add something to make sure you know what it is referring to. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products with different ways of doing things.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for the feed back, its something new to me,.. generic interface...can i do this python or java ..gave an access to the other developers ...so they can send data to database...or?? ...thanks for the information ..i will go through the details

Comment: @ADyson sorry , i don't no these i will delete mysql tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to take data from different sources, and you are using SQL Server, you can look into SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). You'd basically create SSIS packages, one for each incoming data source and transfer the data into one homogeneous database.

Answer (score 0):

These type of implementations and design patterns really depend on your company and the development environment you are working in.

As for choosing the right database, this also depends on the type of data, velocity, volume and common questions your company would like to answer using that data.

Some very general guidelines:

1. Schematic databases differ from "NoSQL" databases
2. Searching within a text is different than searching simpler primitive types and you have to know what you will be doing!
3. If you are able to, converting both VB scripting & C# text files to popular data structure files (i.e JSON, CSV (comma delimited text file is the same)) might help you with storing the data in almost any database.
4. There is no right or wrong in implementing a specific interface for each data supplier, it depends on the alternatives at stake & your coding style
5. Consult with others & ready Case Studies!

Hope that's helpfull

Comment: Well not every Schematic databases differ from "NoSQL" databases.. MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 for example are a SQL and NoSQL database in [one](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/document_store.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes those are comma delimited text files, coming from different developers so for each developer , how do i develop an interface.

Comment: How are these files transfered to you?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Excel’s Power Query tool. You can intake almost any file type (including text files) from multiple locations, cleanse and transform the data easily (you can deliminate as you please), and storage is essentially unlimited as opposed to a regular excel spread sheet which maxes at around 1.4 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your company's situation but PDI (Pentaho Data Integration tool, is good for transformations of data. The Community Edition is free!

However, if you generated them into an excel file Power Query might be a better tool for this project, if your data is relatively small.